# Using click listener on surfaceview inflated layout

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have a surfaceview that opens an alertdialog with an inflated layout, I want to use an image onclicklistener on an imageview from this layout, but i get a nullpointerexception whenever I try to load the dialog, this happens when i set the onclicklistener to the imageview 'tweet'. If i delete the listener it will load without errors. Below is my code

```
      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

                public void run() {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(Panel.this.context);

                     try{ 
                         LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater(); 
                        View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_anime_action, null);


                       adb.setView(dialoglayout)
                       .setNegativeButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
                                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                                ((Activity) context).finish(); 
                                dialog.cancel(); 
                            }
                        }); 
                           ImageView tweet = (ImageView)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.dialog_tweet);
                           tweet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "WORKD");

                            }
                            });
                       }catch(Exception e){Log.d("INFLATER ERROR", e.toString());}
                    adb.show(); 





                }});
```

Comment: You should post your LogCat (stack trace) and mark which line the Exception occurs on.

Comment: currently, the try and catch just prints out java.lang.nullPointerException, this happens when i set the onclicklistener to the imageview 'tweet'. If i delete the listener it will load without errors

Comment: What if you do `dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tweet);` instead? It seems you're using the wrong layout to find your `ImageView`

Comment: That worked, please put your response in an answer so I can accept it :). I over looked the view that I was working with lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be finding the ImageView from `dialogLayout` instead, since that is the Dialog's layout you're working with.

Updated code should be:

```
ImageView tweet = (ImageView) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tweet);
```